# Macro to get real current page

Tags: kentico

Not sure how to label the title of this question. I have a snippet of re-usable content with a Subscribe Icon + Social Icons. This snippet is used in almost every page on the site through a repeater.

What I want to do is to attach the CurrentDocument.DocumentName to the Subscribe Icon in order to know which page people came from, something like this:
*`<a href="/subscribe?p={% CurrentDocument.DocumentName #%}">Subscribe</a>`* However, looks like that doesn't work. This string shows in the address bar when click on the link: `www.domain.com/subscribe?p={%%20CurrentDocument.DocumentNamePath%20|(user)|(hash)34ce5eaa55a6a6ad89...%}` I figure because CurrentDocument is actually referring to the snippet itself, not the real current page displaying in the browser. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

Is your repeater transformation aspx?  If so, use `<%# %>`, so `<%# CurrentDocument.DocumentName %>`

Comment: My transformation is really simple, like this <%# Eval("Content") %> to spit out the html. The macro is in the html content.

Comment: @Michelle  If you are using <%#%> in your transformation, then it is an ASPX transformation, which means {%%} won't resolve, those are for Text/XML transformations.

Comment: Ah, got it. I changed it to <%# CurrentDocument.DocumentName %> as your suggestion, but it didn't resolve either. The whole string is in the url. But I noticed in the Editor the opening & closing brackets were turned in to &lt;   and  &gt; . I'm not sure if that made it not working.

Comment: You might have to use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: Macros are not supported in ASCX transformations. So the CurrentDocument will not work. You need to use text/HTML transformation to use this macro or, in ASCX transformation use <%#Eval("DocumentName")%> - the DocumentName column must be specified in the Columns property of the repeater together with all other columns you are using in your transformation.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an ASCX transformation it is like a web user control, so you can call C# methods, try this

```
<%# CMS.MacroEngine.MacroResolver.Resolve("{%CurrentDocument.DocumentName#%}")%>
```

Or you can do linke in this in ACSX transformation:

```
<script runat="server">
    string test = "";

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        test = CMS.MacroEngine.MacroResolver.Resolve("{%CurrentDocument.DocumentName#%}");
    }
</script>
<h1><%# test%></h1>
```

Consult [MacroResolver class](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/10_0/api/html/T_CMS_MacroEngine_MacroResolver.htm) for other methods

P.S. Sorry I didnt check my answer in Kenitco for the frist time. Just make sure you calling MacroResolver from the right name space.

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: If this is an ASCX transformation it is like a web user control. So you can C# methods, my bad I didnt check, for 11 it should be:
<%# CMS.MacroEngine.MacroResolver.Resolve("{%CurrentDocument.DocumentName#%}")%>